# Vertical skips in paragraphs in L3

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse

Consider the following:

> TeX features some macros for fixed-length spacing.
>
> `\smallskip` Inserts a small space in vertical mode (between two paragraphs).
>
> `\medskip` Inserts a medium space in vertical mode (between two paragraphs).
>
> `\bigskip` Inserts a big space in vertical mode (between two paragraphs).

Are there any existing L3 code that redefines these vertical skips? If not, what would be the correct way to create similar commands with L3 syntax?

Note that the `interface3.pdf` defines `\skip_vertical:N` which is equivalent to the TeX primitive `\vskip`.

Comment: interface3 documents expl3 which is a low level programming layer, document level constructs are not covered. As the document level infrastructure is latex2e, the current definitions are already correct so it isn't clear what definition you are looking for with your question for a "correct implementation"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What I intend to ask is whether the vskips above have been rewritten using L3 syntax.

Comment: not really as mostly they are an instance of `\vspace`  which is firmly on the 2e side of things `\@bsphack`,  `\@restorepar` etc.